# Error inflating class <unknown> is pointing to the custom adapter class

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, layout-inflater

[image][image]This happened when I changed my button into a material button and provided overridden style as a background

This is the error pointing field:

```
public RecycleViewCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<bigModel> ModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.ModelArrayList = ModelArrayList;
```

This is the error

```
     118 27852-27852/com.a.b E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.a.b, PID: 27852
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #236 in com.a.b:layout/saved_job_recycleview: Binary XML file line #236 in com.a.b:layout/saved_job_recycleview: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #236 in com.a.b:layout/saved_job_recycleview: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
```

[image: e]

Comment: `Caused by: ` tells me this is just a chained exception, not even potentially the first or last one. You should include the entire stack trace and the code which is causing it, which we cannot see with the current information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved when I removed the material button in my recycle view item.

I changed

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:strokeColor="@style/blue"
                                android:textColor="#2196F3"                       
 android:background="@drawable/blue_border_btn"
                                android:text="View " />
```

> to this:

```
                       <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="28"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_border_btn"
                        android:text="View " />
```

> But I can't resolve the symbol R error. I also need to use the stroke color on the button.